# Javascript location in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Im trying to locate certain javascript code in the codebase with no luck.  This code appears in the head of every page. Note that it isnt a link to a file but certain code embedded in the head. I have tried the following ways but no luck

1. local.xml
2. head.phtml
3. page.phtml and all page templates
4. page.xml
5. Text search in codebase with keyword  and
   keyword '{variablename}'
6. Database search   keyword '{variablename}'

but no results so far

Have a missed something? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Loveleen

Comment: Is it magento core JS or 3rd party code? any specifics for the `{variablename}` your searching for may help.

Comment: its actually analytics code that was inserted and its not via magento's Google Analytics module. It was done by a previous developer and am not sure how and where it as inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the page templates still generally reflect the native Magento structure, if it's in the `<head>` of the page, then it can only be coming from one of three places:

- The page template (1column.phtml, 3columns.phtml, etc.).
- The `<head>` include file head.phtml.
- An include of one of the first two.

I know you said you already looked in both of those places, but you can help narrow down the source by comparing what you can see in those locations with what you see in the generated page source. Is the analytics code you're trying to locate before or after something you can see in those template files?

Also make sure that you're looking in the template files of the correct theme.

Comment: Ok got it.. it was under System>Config>Design>Misc Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it.. it was under System>Config>Design>Misc Scripts